# Не отправляет письмо в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

На сайте есть кастомная форма обратной связи, которая использует для отправки почты функцию wp_mail() и почта отправляется и приходит на почтовый ящик.
Я хочу уведомить автора о том, что пост опубликован, для этого я использую такой код:

```
function notifyauthor($post_id) {

$post = get_post($post_id);
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";

$message = "
      Hi ".$author->display_name.",

      Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.

      View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."

      Thanks"
      ;

   wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'notifyauthor');
```

Вставляю его в файл functions.php , но не приходит письмо. 
Возможная проблема была с отправкой через стандартные средства wordpress и я настроил smtp по [этой статье](http://seostage.ru/reshenie-problemy-otpravki-pochty-v-wordpress.html).
Проверил роботоспособность формы, она работает. 
Проверил, приходят ли уведомления при публикации поста - уведомления не приходят.

Подскажите, где я неправильно что делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы проверили и уверены что `wp_mail()` работает, проблема может быть именно в передаваемых значениях при вызове функции `notifyauthor()`, например в переменной `$author->user_email` пусто. Для проверки сделайте следующее:

```
$checkEmail = wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message);
print_r($checkEmail); exit();
```

и посмотрите есть ли ошибки...

Comment: Проверку 
$checkEmail = wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message);
print_r($checkEmail); exit();
сделал, на почту ничего не пришло, ошибок нет

Comment: На почту может и не прийти, смысл данной проверки сделать выход из php кода и проверить данные. Вы как вызываете функцию notifyauthor($post_id); ?  после сабмита вызываете данную функцию?

Comment: я не втавляю данную функцию в форму отправки, я вставил код в functions.php. Изначально я писал о форме обратной связи для того, чтобы указать, что отправка письма с помощью wp_mail() работает на сайте. Потом я написал, что хочу уведомить автора, когда пост будет опубликован, для этого я вставляю предоставленный выше код в файл function.php и все. Тоесть код должин срабатывать на ивент сохранения поста.

Comment: [ссылка откуда я это брал Method3](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-email-authors-when-their-articles-are-published-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Еще скажу, зачем я делаю эту отправку. Я хочу сделать плагин, и сейчас по кусочкам пробую делать реализацию этого. Также я задавал вопрос по этому поводу [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619516/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: т.е после настройки SMTP вы проверили, почту получате ? например из контактной формы(если есть)

Comment: да, почта приходит, как ранше [скрин](http://prntscr.com/e1gh81)

Comment: Попробуйте 'насильно' вызвать функцию + передайте POST ID(любой post id)
add_action('publish_post', 'notifyauthor',$post_id);

Comment: вызов сделал так: `add_action('publish_post', 'notifyauthor',79);` но publish_post уже произошол или при вызове функции все повторяется? и на почту ничего не пришло

Comment: Возможно нет, лучше попробовать вставить ID POST который отключён.
Если почту получаете на gmail - проверьте папку Спам.
Если проблема не прошла попробуйте вставить ваш эл.адресс именно в wp_mail 
 wp_mail('mashmail@gmail.com', $subject, $message);

Comment: попробовал, но на почту всеравно ничего не пришло, и в спаме нет, пробовал также на action save_post, ничего не пришло

Comment: значит ваша функция не вызывается, вставьте вызов функции notifyauthor(79)  в index.php и просто перезагрузите страницу

Comment: Возвращает NULL тоесть ничего нет, почему только?

Comment: Вот поэтому я в начале посоветовал проверить данные пошагам ))

1. $post = get_post($post_id);
print_r($post ); exit();

2. $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
print_r($author ); exit();
....
чтобы понять где и какие данные не приходят, если после проверки, все данные приходят но почта не отправляется установи и настрой SMTP плагин 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Comment: проверил существует ли id поста и его мета и существует ли автор - все есть, когда пробую настриоить SMTP то выдает ошибку:

`Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@main-hosting.eu to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите, где я неправильно что делаю?

В функции [wp_mail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) нет параметра `$headers`.
В нём нужно во `From` подставлять адрес с домена, а адрес для ответа в 'Reply To'. Из-за этого сервер может не отправлять почту.

См также 
https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D1%83%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-php-mailer/

https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=45774

http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=45779

Кроме того рекомендую поставить [плагин для логирования почты](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/log-emails/)

Comment: в вашей же ссылке документации написанно что $headers не объязательна ))
$headers -  (string|array) (Optional) Additional headers.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно. Исправил. То ли раньше был обязательным то ли я запамятовал. Но это всё равно одна из частых причин проблемы. Тем более после последних событий.

Comment: тоже возможно...